# Jquery inserting dom to wrong tab

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table that i am inserting to a page using datatables using this jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //alert('this was loaded.');
    $.noConflict();
     $('#outbox-1').datetimepicker();
     $('#outbox-2').datetimepicker();
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatable.employees') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'Id' },
            { data: 'users_full_names', name: 'Full Names' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'Email' },
            { data: 'users_telephone_number', name: 'Telephone' },
            { data: 'users_credits', name: 'Credits' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'Last Seen' },
            { data: 'users_profile_picture', name: 'Profile Picture' },
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the html

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1success">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">
<thead>
<tr>

<th>id</th>
<th>Full Names</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Telephone</th>
<th>Credits</th>
<th>Last Seen</th>
<th>Profile Picture</th>

</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2success">
</div>
</div>
```

This is the screenshot of a datatables

[image]

and this screenshot shwo how the dom is inserted even on neighbouring tab that does not even have the target id by the datatables

[image]

Upon inspecting via the inspector, the table can be found in the second tab. The first time the table is loaded, the other tab's content remains in place and no space is taken erroneously by the other tabs datatable. Its when i click the datatables tab and click the second does the problem appear.

Why is the datatables appearing in the second tab?.

Other tabs html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2success">
                              <form>
                              <div class="form-group">
            <style>.mb{margin-bottom:20px;}.ml{margin-left:15px;} .btnr{margin-right:25px;}</style>
            <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label">One</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Two</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Three</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Four</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Five</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>

              <div class="col-xs-3 mb">
              <label class="control-label ">Six</label>
                 <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 ml ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnr pull-right">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
                            </div>
```

Comment: can you copy the html code from your other tabs? This might shed some light onto why the table appears in the wrong tab.

Comment: I have added the other tabs html

Comment: I kinda solved it by doing away with tabs  and loading each tab from the server each time.